# Can i add a class to panel control in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0, code-behind

i have a dynamic table that creates a div (new panel) for every TD and i want to give this div a class...

Can i add with Attributes.Add or with cssClass a class to the panel?

I am asking becouse i tried with both and got the same resault.... browser crash!!!

Every other attribute works great, and i just don't understand why....

```
 Panel div = new Panel();
 div.ID = "div" + "_" + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString();
 div.Height = _CellHeight;
 div.Width = _CellWidth;
```

.
.
.

```
div.CssClass = "droppable";
td.Controls.Add(div);
```

trying to add the all code:

```
<link href="Styles/Kanpai.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
    .draggable { width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color:Blue;}
    .draggable_big { width: 40px; height: 40px; background-color:Blue;}
    .draggable_wide { width: 40px; height: 20px; background-color:Blue;}
    .draggable_long { width: 20px; height: 40px; background-color:Blue;}
    .droppable { width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color:Red;}
</style>
<script src="JavaScript/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JavaScript/jquery-ui-1.8.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JavaScript/Accordion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".draggable").draggable({ snap: '.droppable' });
        $(".draggable_big").draggable({ snap: '.droppable' });
        $(".draggable_wide").draggable({ snap: '.droppable' });
        $(".draggable_long").draggable({ snap: '.droppable' });
        $( ".draggable_big" ).draggable( "option", "cursor", 'move' );
        $( ".draggable_big" ).draggable( "option", "cursorAt", {right:15,top:15} );
        $( ".draggable_wide" ).draggable( "option", "cursor", 'move' );
        $( ".draggable_wide" ).draggable( "option", "cursorAt", {right:15,top:15} );
        $( ".draggable_long" ).draggable( "option", "cursor", 'move' );
        $( ".draggable_long" ).draggable( "option", "cursorAt", {right:15,top:15} );
        $(".droppable").droppable({
            drop: function() {alert('dropped:' + $(this).attr('id')); }
        });
        $( ".droppable" ).droppable( "option", "tolerance", 'pointer' );
    });
</script>
```

רשימת האיזורים לבחירה:
                    
                    
                        בחר איזור:

this is the code in the parrent file, the one that is calling the UC that is building the table...

now. the UC:

```
 public void CreatTable()
{
    //לולאה ליצירת טבלה דינאמית לפי בחירת המתכנת
    for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt16(_RowNum); i++)
    {
        //שורה חדשה
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        //קביעת זהות דינאמית לשורה
        tr.ID = "tr" + i.ToString();
        //לולאה ליצירת העמודות בשורה
        for (int j = 0; j < Convert.ToInt16(_ColNum); j++)
        {
            //תא חדש
            TableCell td = new TableCell();
            //קבלת זהות לתא לפי השורה והעמודה
            td.ID = "td" + "_" + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString();
            //קביערת רוחב עמודה
            td.Width = _CellWidth;
            //קביעת גובה שורה
            td.Height = _CellHeight;
            //בקוד DIV יצירת אלמנט מסוג
            Panel div = new Panel();
            //קביעת הזהות לאלמנט
            div.ID = "div" + "_" + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString();
            //קביעת גובה ורוחב כמו התא
            div.Height = _CellHeight;
            div.Width = _CellWidth;

            //בדיקה האם יש אובייקטים לאותו האיזור
            if (_ObjectsForTable != null)
            {
                //אם כן, לכל תא בטבלה נבדוק האם יש לו רשומה מתאימה בבסיס המידע
                //מעבר על כל הרשומות בטבלה
                for (Int16 DataSetIndex = 0; DataSetIndex < _ObjectsForTable.Tables[0].Rows.Count; DataSetIndex++)
                {
                    //בדיקה האם האינדקסים בטבלה של הרשומה הנוכחית מתאימים לתא הנוכחי 
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(_ObjectsForTable.Tables[0].Rows[DataSetIndex]["RowID"]) == i &&
                        Convert.ToInt32(_ObjectsForTable.Tables[0].Rows[DataSetIndex]["ColID"]) == j)
                    { 
                        //אם כן, נייצר תמונה למסך לפי סוג האובייקט
                        switch(Convert.ToInt32(_ObjectsForTable.Tables[0].Rows[DataSetIndex]["ObjectTypeID"]))
                        {
                            case 1:
                                div.Style.Add("background-image", "url(Images/Objects/Tables/TableFull.jpg);");
                                div.Style.Add("position", "absolute");
                                div.Style.Add("width", "40px");
                                div.Style.Add("height", "30px");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                div.Style.Add("background-image", "url(Images/Objects/Tables/BarChair.png);");
                                div.Style.Add("position", "absolute");
                                div.Style.Add("width", "20px");
                                div.Style.Add("height", "15px");
                                break;
                        }
                        //div.Style.Add("background-image", "url(Images/Objects/Tables/TableFull.jpg);"); 
                    }
                }
            }
            div.CssClass = "droppable";
            //לתא DIVהוספת ה
            td.Controls.Add(div);
            //בדיקה האם צריך גבולות או לא לפני שמכניסים את התא לשורה
            if (_IsBorder)
                td.Style.Add("border", "1px solid black;");
            else
                td.Style.Add("border", "none;");
            //הוספת התא לשורה
            tr.Controls.Add(td);
        }
        //הוספת השורה לטבלה
        tblMain.Controls.Add(tr);         
    }
    tblMain.Style.Add("position", "relative");
    //אם נבחרה תמונת רקע ויש תמונה רקע יש לשים אותה 
    if (_IsBackGroundImage == true && _BackGroundImage != "" && _BackGroundImage != null)
        tblMain.Style["background-image"] = _BackGroundImage;


}
```

I told you it's a long one....:-)

Isn't it wierd.....?

10x

Comment: Can you describe this "browser crash"? ASP.NET Yellow screen? Browser ends execution and has to close? Hangs? etc..

Comment: A loop the never ends, I can put all the code but it's kind of huge and those are the only lines that has any thing to do with the div from its contruction to append...
and when i take the line: "div.CssClass = "droppable"; of every thing goes back to normal...
I guess the thing i noticed is that in every example they use the Id of the element and i am using the object it self...My questian was if i can use the object and not the ID of the object and if i need to use the id, how can i do it with the code as it is????
10x....

Comment: what does 'droppable' class relate to on the UI? Are you using jQuery-UI or another client-side UI tool? Maybe it's because you are creating too many draggable/droppable divs for the javascript library to handle? (I.e. when you add 'droppable' class to many divs, the UI has to initialize these, when you take the class out, it doesn't - hence the bottleneck...) Perhaps?

Comment: KP, i guess that u are right...But what can i do if i need them???
Is there a solusion or a work around for this problem?

Comment: kp, You were right, i did an experiment with mod and it took some time but i did it....too bad :-( not i can't use drad&drop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all `WebControls`, use the common `.CssClass` property to set or modify the class.

Sounds to me like your issue isn't related to setting a css class, but something else. Setting a class isn't going to cause the browser to crash.

Can you post your entire code, rather than a snippet?